# SQL with AND statements, dynamically building up

Tags: sql, sql-server

Aim: I'm building a dynamic SQL string and want to make the search an AND function

Code type: SQL stored procedure within SQL Server Management Studio

Issue: If the first search is not required then I need to know this (I know because the default is '0' in this case. I feel I'm missing a sitter but don't seem to be able to stackoverflow/Google for the solution.

I set up @QueryString with a default of '' so the functionality will work.

What will fix this?:

I've thought about COALESCE and potential use of IF ELSE within the IF but I am hoping there is clean solution along the lines of

```
SET @QUERYSTRING = IF(@QUERYSTRING = '','', + + ' FIELD1 LIKE ''%' +  LTRIM(RTRIM(@s1)) + '%' )
```

Current example (snippet):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGridSearchTest]
    @s1 NVARCHAR(20), 
    @s2 VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)  = ''
DECLARE @QUERYSTRING NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''


SET @QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM TblTable'
IF @s1 <> '1234xyz'
    SET @QUERYSTRING =    @QUERYSTRING  + ' Field1 LIKE ''%' +  LTRIM(RTRIM(@s1)) + '%'

IF @s2 <> '1234xyz'
    SET @QUERYSTRING =    @QUERYSTRING  + ' Field2  LIKE ''%' +  LTRIM(RTRIM@s2)) + '%'

IF LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@QUERYSTRING)))  > 0 
    SET @QUERY = LTRIM(RTRIM(@QUERY)) + ' WHERE   ' +  LTRIM(RTRIM(@QUERYSTRING))    + '''' 

EXECUTE(@QUERY) 
END
```

Comment: You could set up your initial query as `SELECT * FROM TblTable WHERE  1 = 1`. Then each subsequent predicate you set up can just be a complete on beginning with `AND`, you won' t need to worry about whether or not it is needed

Comment: I'm intrigued about 1= 1, how what etc...

Comment: and is this what Joe has put as his answer or can the lines with @conditionadded  be dropped?

Comment: `1 =1` is just a meaningless predicate that will always evaluate to true, it just means you never need to check where to start your next condition with `AND` or `WHERE`, it will always be `AND`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand better your issue:

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGridSearchTest]
@s1 NVARCHAR(20), 
@s2 VARCHAR(20)

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)  = ''
    DECLARE @QUERYSTRING NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    DECLARE @conditionadded char(1) = 'N'

    SET @QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM TblTable'

    IF @s1 <> '1234xyz'
    BEGIN
        SET @QUERYSTRING = ' Field1 LIKE ''%' +  LTRIM(RTRIM(@s1)) + '%'
        SET @conditionadded = 'Y'
    END
    IF @s2 <> '1234xyz'
    BEGIN
        IF (@conditionadded = 'Y')
        BEGIN
            SET @QUERYSTRING = @QUERYSTRING + ' AND '
        END
        SET @QUERYSTRING = @QUERYSTRING  + ' Field2  LIKE ''%' +  LTRIM(RTRIM@s2)) + '%'
        SET @conditionadded = 'Y'
    END

    IF (@conditionadded = 'Y') 
    BEGIN
        SET @QUERY = LTRIM(RTRIM(@QUERY)) + ' WHERE ' +  LTRIM(RTRIM(@QUERYSTRING))    + '''' 
    END

    EXECUTE(@QUERY) 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a dynamic query? Why not use something like this:

```
select
 Whatever
from MyTable
where
 (@s1 = '1234xyz' or Field1 = @s1)
 and
 (@s2 = '1234xyz' or Field2 = @s2)
```

This avoids a security hole, and depending on your query patterns and data set, it might even be faster. And of course, it's pretty easy to read, and you don't have to deal with SQL in strings :)

Comment: There will be around 20 fields sadly otherwise I'd do that.

Comment: If you are doing this approach you should also use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to ensure any available indexes can be used.

Comment: @GarethD No, definitely not. You can use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` if you have reasonable proof it's actually going to help in practice, but not otherwise. Guessing around performance rarely gets you good results. If your indices are being used sub-optimally, sure, `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` might help. But wait for the data before trying this - the query compilation time may be non-trivial.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "If you are doing this approach you should *probably* use OPTION (RECOMPILE)". Yes, there are disadvantages and there may be occasions where the improved execution plan may be outweighed by query compilation but in most cases this won't be the case, it would be more guess work to say don't use it than it would to say use it. According to the conclusion in [Erland Sommarskog's atricle on the subject](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) - *"Solutions with static SQL almost always use OPTION (RECOMPILE)"*

Comment: @GarethD Well, if you're almost always searching by one of the possible conditions, `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` will tend to perform best no matter other constraints, really (as long as you have indices, of course :D). That's what Erland is referring to - a totally dynamic query written as static SQL, basically. There's plenty of cases where a properly biased query will work almost as well, while avoiding the cost of making new execution plans all the time - fine tuning DB performance is far from trivial. It's very easy to *add* `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to a query when you find it performing badly.

Comment: @GarethD Though I admit I'm a bit biased, since I've tuned a poorly designed database recently, which had terrible execution plan reuse, causing *systemic* performance issues. The real problem isn't the query performance itself, but the wide-reaching effects of poor plan-reuse - the system in question was running at 100% CPU at peak load (for hours at a time) with awful response times, exclusively due to a single query that avoided plan reuse (the fix took about ten seconds, of course). It's usually easier to tweak a single query than to find a global issue like this.